# Understanding OpenZeppelin's Context contract

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin-contracts, meta-transactions

I'm new to solidity and trying to understand OpenZeppelin's [`Context` contract](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Context.sol). At the time of writing, the documentation says:

> While these are generally available via msg.sender and msg.data, they should not be accessed in such a direct manner, since when dealing with meta-transactions the account sending and paying for execution may not be the actual sender (as far as an application is concerned).
>
> This contract is only required for intermediate, library-like contracts.

I kind of understand at a high level that `msg.sender` can be different from the actual sender for a meta-transaction, but I do not understand how using `Context`'s `_msgSender()` or `_msgData()` helps with that. Both functions are simply returning `msg.sender` and `msg.data` and they look no different from directly accessing `msg.sender` or `msg.data`.

OpenZeppelin's `Ownable` uses `_msgSender()` in its constructor and modifier `onlyOwner()` but I don't understand how that's different from hardcoding `msg.sender`.

A specific example where calling `_msgSender()` is different from `msg.sender` would be very helpful!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question has been asked and answered on the OZ forum here : https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/help-understanding-contract-context/10579.

The `_msg.sender` and `_msg.data` functions are in fact overridden in the OZ smart contract [ERC2771Context](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/metatx/ERC2771Context.sol) which implements the [EIP-2771 : Secure Protocol for Native Meta Transactions](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2771).

`_msg.sender` here allows a recipient contract to retrieve the original sender in the case of a meta-transaction sent by a trusted forwarder :

```
function _msgSender() internal view virtual override returns (address sender) {
    if (isTrustedForwarder(msg.sender)) {
        // The assembly code is more direct than the Solidity version using `abi.decode`.
        assembly {
            sender := shr(96, calldataload(sub(calldatasize(), 20)))
        }
    } else {
        return super._msgSender();
    }
}
```

From the EIP-2771 :

> The Trusted Forwarder is responsible for calling the Recipient
> contract and MUST append the address of the Transaction Signer (20
> bytes of data) to the end of the call data.

Comment: original sender can be received via tx.origin as well