# Transferring NFT Tokens without the ownership of the tokens but approving the contract address as operator

Tags: solidity, tokens, nft, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-creatures/blob/master/contracts/ERC721Tradable.sol

Someone please explain me the function at line 91

Comment: Those contracts appear too be meta transactions https://docs.openzeppelin.com/learn/sending-gasless-transactions.  See this explanation for the OpenZeppelin implementation https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/99250/understanding-openzeppelins-context-contract.